# How to identify which thread is holding a mutex

Tags: c++, mutex

Is it possible to identify which thread is holding the mutex? I'm facing an issue in which one of my thread has indefinitely got blocked in acquiring a mutex. I'm using `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mut)` syntax to acquire a lock which basically follows RAII pattern.

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example code snippet.

Comment: Is that function called recursively directly or indirectly?

Comment: Do you intend to do it while debugging or do you plan to develop a feature where your application dynamically does something according to the thread holding the mutex? If your answer is debug only, you could define a `debug_lock_guard` who spits debug logs each time the mutex is being manipulated.

Comment: You can get the id of the current thread with `std::this_thread::get_id()`. You can use this to tag a lock with a thread id

Comment: @Jarod42 the function gets called only from one thread directly, inside which I'm calling `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current thread id via `get_id`:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>


void foo() {
    {
        static std::mutex mut;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mut);
        std::cout << "thread holding the lock: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
        std::cout << "Hello \n";
    }
    std::cout << "thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " no longer holds the lock \n";
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1(&foo);
    std::thread t2(&foo);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/PcWq5vao8):

```
thread holding the lock: 140607394023168
Hello 
thread 140607394023168 no longer holds the lock 
thread holding the lock: 140607385630464
Hello 
thread 140607385630464 no longer holds the lock
```

My next idea would be to wrap the `std::mutex` into a `my_mutex` which remembers which thread currently holds the lock. Though, that would require to use another mutex to synchronize access to that information, hence logging seems to be the better way.

Comment: Thanks for that idea. Are there any tools that help in solving these kind of problems?